# Instagram API Relationship Endpoints followed-by

Tags: ios, json, swift, instagram-api

I am trying to get a list of users that is following me, but it doesn't seems to give me any result. This is the code I am using:

```
func followers(){
        print("1")
        let url = URL(string: "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/followed-by?access_token=\(self.currentAccessTolken)")

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with:url!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else { return }
            print("2")
            do {
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as! [String:Any]
                print("3")
                if let userJson = json["data"] as? [String : AnyObject] {
                    print("4")
                    if let username = userJson["username"] as? String {
                        print("username: \(username)")
                    }
                    if let fullname = userJson["full_name"] as? String {
                        print("full name: \(fullname)")
                    }
                }

            } catch let error as NSError {
                print(error)
            }
        }).resume()
    }
```

API: https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/relationships/#get_users_followed_by

The `printn("1")`, `printn("2")` and `printn("3")` shows up in the event log, but not the `printn("4")`. Also it doesn't give me any result of either username or full name. The scopes I use is: `basic+follower_list+public_content+relationships`. Anyone knows what may be wrong here?

Comment: "data" is an array of dictionaries, but you are trying to cast it as a dictionary.

Comment: @conarch How exactly? It tried changing the `["data"]` line with this; `if let userJson = json["data"] as? Dictionary<String, Any> `, but it still doesn't work..

Comment: Are you in sandbox mode? if you are, you will not get any results, read docs

Comment: That's still a dictionary.  Cast it as [[String : AnyObject]] to get it as an array of dictionaries.